# how to remove horizontal line in circumference with plot()

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot a circumference.
The function to draw points on the circumference is:

```
d_cir = function (a=1){
x = seq(-a,a,.005)
y = sqrt(a^2-x^2)
x = matrix(c(x,x), ncol=1)
y = matrix(c(y,-y), ncol=1)
matrix(c(x, y), ncol = 2)
}
```

Then i plot:

```
plot(d_cir(), asp = 1, type="l")
```

[image]

How to remove the horizontal line from plot?
Thank you, Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tiny adjustment. You want c(x, x) to go from -1 to 1 to 1 to -1 so you need to reverse the order of x the second time. Since y is symmetrical y and rev(y) are the same so you don't need to reverse that one:

```
d_cir = function (a){
x = seq(-a,a,.005)
y = sqrt(a^2-x^2)
x = matrix(c(x, rev(x)), ncol=1)
y = matrix(c(y,-y), ncol=1)
matrix(c(x, y), ncol = 2)
}
plot(d_cir(1), asp = 1, type="l")
```

This does the same thing but the code is a bit simpler:

```
d_cir <- function (a){
     x <- seq(-a, a, .005)
     y <- sqrt(a^2 - x^2)
     x <- c(x, rev(x))
     y <- c(y, -y)
     cbind(x, y)
}
plot(d_cir(1), asp = 1, type="l")
```